# Monthly Gold and Oil prices going back to 1920s

Tags: data-request, historical

I am trying to find **Monthly** prices or returns for `Gold` and `Oil` going back in time until 1920s. Yearly data is available, but I wanted to check if someone has come across monthly time series too.

Comment: If you're into pain, you could use something like https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/ (old newspapers) to find the data in various local and national papers.

Comment: Have you tried https://fred.stlouisfed.org/?